# Organize a list of items into different lists based off of keywords in original list items

Tags: python, list

I've been working on a program that will take a list of recipes and sort them into different lists based off of ingredients mentioned in the URL to allow for a search based off of ingredients. The output for the code below produces an empty list:

```
recipes = ["example.com/cherry-pie/", "example.com/caramel-apples/", "example.com/blueberry-banana-bread/", "example.com/apple-fruit-salad/"]
fruit = []
apple = []
banana = []
blueberry = []
cherry = []

def fruitLoop():
    for item in recipes:
        link = item
        fruitwords = ["fruit", "apple", "banana", "blueberry", "cherry"]
        appleWord = ("apple")
        bananaWord = ("banana")
        blueberryWord  = ("blueberry")
        cherryWord = ("cherry")
        if link in fruitwords:
            fruit.append(link)
        if link in appleWord:
            apple.append(link)
        if link in bananaWord:
            banana.append(link)
        if link in blueberryWord:
            blueberry.append(link)
        if link in cherryWord:
            cherry.append(link)
    print(fruit)

fruitLoop()
```

Originally I had

```
if fruitwords in link:
    fruit.append(link)
```

but that produced an error because it expects a string rather than a list.

I gave an example list for this question as the original list of recipes is much longer and doesn't include just fruit lists. My expected outcome would be something like

```
print(fruit)
# ["example.com/cherry-pie/", "example.com/caramel-apples/", "example.com/blueberry-banana-bread/", "example.com/apple-fruit-salad/"]
print(apple)
# ["example.com/caramel-apples/", "example.com/apple-fruit-salad/"]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You're so close! Before your block of if statements, `print("link =", link)` and `print("link in fruitwords?", link in fruitwords)`... to realize the discrepancy

Comment: Why do you do `link = item`? Either use `for link in recipes:` or use `item` in the rest of the loop body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have changed you code little bit to do what you want.

i think this code is what you want :

```py
recipes = ["example.com/cherry-pie/", "example.com/caramel-apples/", "example.com/blueberry-banana-bread/", "example.com/apple-fruit-salad/"]
fruit = []
apple = []
banana = []
blueberry = []
cherry = []

def fruitLoop():
    for item in recipes:
        link = item

        fruitwords = ["fruit", "apple", "banana", "blueberry", "cherry"]

        appleWord = ("apple")
        bananaWord = ("banana")
        blueberryWord  = ("blueberry")
        cherryWord = ("cherry")

        for i in fruitwords:
            if i in link:
                fruit.append(link)
        

        if appleWord in link:
            apple.append(link)
    

        if bananaWord in link:
            banana.append(link)
    

        if blueberryWord in link:
            blueberry.append(link)
    

        if cherryWord in link:
            cherry.append(link)

fruitLoop()

fruit = list(set(fruit))
apple = list(set(apple))
banana = list(set(banana))
blueberry = list(set(blueberry))
cherry = list(set(cherry))

print(fruit)
```

Comment: `appleWord` is a string, not a list or tuple. So you're iterating over the letters.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right. i changed it now. thanks

Comment: Since the variable name is singular, I don't think there are supposed to be multiple items that you need to loop over.

Comment: @Barmar you are right again , and i changed it again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some of your conditions are backwards. For example:

```
if link in appleWord:
```

should be

```
if appleWord in link:
```

You should make the same change for all the other tests of a single string. The syntax in general is

```
if substring in longerString:
```

Meanwhile,

```
if link in fruitWords:
```

will never be true, since `link` is a full URL, but `fruitWords` doesn't contain URLs. What you want is:

```
if any(word in link for word in fruitWords):
```